# Classification of data in alphabetic order in r

Tags: r

I have a sample data below.

```
Earthquake.Name  Mw Name.of.the.tank.site Dia..m. H..m.  H.D Fluid.type Fluid.level PGA..g..selected.for.analysis
1          Alaska 9.2      Nikiska Refinery     9.1  14.6 1.60      water        1.00                          0.20
2          Alaska 9.2      Nikiska Refinery    21.3  14.6 0.69  crude oil        0.33                          0.20
3          Alaska 9.2     Anchorage Airport    13.7   9.8 0.71       fuel        1.00                          0.21
4          Alaska 9.2     Anchorage Airport    36.6   9.8 0.27        oil        1.00                          0.21
5          Alaska 9.2        Anchorage area    16.8   7.0 0.42   fuel oil        1.00                          0.21
6          Alaska 9.2      Nikiska Refinery    43.9  17.1 0.39  crude oil        0.70                          0.20
  PGA..g..from.shape.file
1                    0.20
2                    0.20
3                    0.21
4                    0.21
5                    0.21
6                    0.20
```

And the structure of data is below.

```
fb<-structure(list(Earthquake.Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Alaska", class = "factor"), Mw = c(9.2, 
    9.2, 9.2, 9.2, 9.2, 9.2, 9.2), Name.of.the.tank.site = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Anchorage Airport", "Anchorage area", 
    "Nikiska Refinery", "Port of Whittier (U.S Army Petroleum Distribution tank farm)"
    ), class = "factor"), Dia..m. = c(9.1, 21.3, 13.7, 36.6, 16.8, 
    43.9, 93), H..m. = c(14.6, 14.6, 9.8, 9.8, 7, 17.1, 27.7), H.D = c(1.6, 
    0.69, 0.71, 0.27, 0.42, 0.39, 0.3), Fluid.type = structure(c(5L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("crude oil", "fuel", "fuel oil", 
    "oil", "water"), class = "factor"), Fluid.level = c(1, 0.33, 
    1, 1, 1, 0.7, 0.7), PGA..g..selected.for.analysis = c(0.2, 0.2, 
    0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.2, 0.384), PGA..g..from.shape.file = c(0.2, 
    0.2, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.2, 0.384)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -7L))
```

I want to organize data to obtain it in alphabetic order by fluid type in the same file.

i.e; crude oils should be at top, then fuel, fuel oil, oil and water respectively.

Comment: Maybe use `oder`: `fb <- fb[order(fb$Fluid.type),]`

Comment: Or to use the `levels` of `Fluid.type` when they are ordered: `fb <- fb[order(unclass(fb$Fluid.type)),]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data frame, the levels of the Fluid type are not in alphabetical order

```
fb$Fluid.level = factor(fb$Fluid.level,levels=sort(levels(fb$Fluid.type)))
fb[order(fb$Fluid.type),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can youse the tidy method:

```
library(tidyverse)
fb<-fb%>%arrange(Fluid.type)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr package which is a helpful library for data cleaning and manipulation

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(fb,Fluid.type)
```